# How to cite LandSat 8?

Tags: geography, reference-request

I'm wondering how to quote a Landsat mission product. I have seen many ways, but I can't decide which one is the best. Thus, I would like to know if there is a standard for the minimum information that should be quoted such as mission, data, sensor, orbita/ponto. Furthermore, do I have to include a link to access the image?

If anyone has any tips or guess on the subject would be grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Landsat products obtained via various sources (ex the EROS Center) can have their own requirements when using their products. For instance the [EROS Data Citation page](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/data-citation) indicate that they are quite open regarding how their documents are cited and require the following acknowledgement only. For example

> Acknowledgement:
>
> Data available from the U.S. Geological Survey.
>
> See USGS Visual Identity System Guidance (link is external) for further details.
>
> Questions concerning the use or redistribution of USGS data should be directed to: ask@usgs.gov (link sends e-mail) or 1-888-ASK-USGS (1-888-275-8747).

Metadata files attached to images are often filled with useful information. Usual relevant information for a technical or scientific paper are the moment of acquisition, the scale, the bands, the name of the sensor, maybe the series of the product, maybe there is a serial number too, possibly a URL.

I have cited in a recent paper the following for Landsat 7, and did not went into much details because it was a reworked product (a special issued mosaic), which was convenient for our scope:

NRCan, Canada Centre for Remote Sensing. A complete orthorectified Landsat-7 mosaic
of the Canadian Arctic archipelago, August 2010. URL http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/-/(urn:iso:series)a-complete-orthorectified-landsat-7-mosaic-of-the-canadian-arctic-archipelago

Comment: @Michael thank you for the update. I think there was some significative upgrades for security on USGS related resources recently - many sites being reorganized and/or changing for secure http protocol among other things. Let's keep an eye for broken links !